# WinSock and IOCP readiness notification

Tags: c++, c, windows, winsock, iocp

I was reading [this post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19541691) where someone mentions the ability to get notifications when a socket is ready to read instead of getting a notification when reading is finished - by submitting a 0 sized buffer.

```
...
WSABUF DataBuf;
DataBuf.len = 0;
DataBuf.buf = NULL;
...
rc = WSARecv(ConnSocket, &DataBuf, 1, &RecvBytes, &Flags, &RecvOverlapped, NULL);
```

However, I couldn't find anything in the documentation about that so I am a bit worried. Is this common practice and safe to do?

Comment: Check [ IO completion ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports)

Comment: @VictorGubin Thanks! I was looking at that but I couldn't find any related information

Comment: what sense at all pass zero size buffer ? just pass not empty buffer

Comment: and anyway in all case you only got notify when I/O complete. no any sense in 0 buffer

Comment: @RbMm mostly for portability (compatibility with epoll and the like)

Comment: i nothing understand in portability and are exist sense in this, but all this absolute unrelated to IOCP. *IOCP can sort of emulate readiness notification* - absolute senseless and wrong assumption. iocp nothing emulate. never. simply when I/O on file object complete and file object is bind to IOCP - packet queued to this IOCP. if you begin asynchronous I/O via `WSARecv` - when it finished - you got notification to IOCP. are you pass 0 or not 0 buffer - how here related at all ?! notification will be when io finished (if it not synchronous fail do invalid parameter/handle)

Comment: you confuse completely different and unrelated things.
if file is bind to IOCP and I/O operation finished on this file - you got notification via IOCP. all.
what is I/O operation, what buffers you pass, are I/O operation at all have buffers - unrelate  here at all.
pass emprty buffers i sure no sense - because in this case you need again call recv with not empty buffers.
what sense do this, when you from begin can begin I/O operation with not empty buffers ?
it will complete at the same time, if you use empty buffers.
simply if case empty buffers need 2 I/O operation instead 1.

Comment: so in short - readiness notification not exist at all. iocp here unrelated. use empty buffers - have no any sense

Comment: I don't know Julius's use case but there are use cases where a readiness indication rather than a completion indication would be useful. My concrete example is trying to us a library which does asynchronous network operations itself but allows hooking in a "readiness provider". Things like `select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()`, and `kqueue()` can do that naturally. io_uring does support `poll` as an operation. On Windows it seems the proper way is to use completion ports but without a readiness signal the library can't be used.